# Appending an element inside the child of another element

Tags: javascript, append, appendchild

I am trying to append a link ("a" tag) to a child of the "topBar" element.
Here is what i've got so far:

```
document.getElementById('topBar').innerHTML += '<a href="http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/" target="blank">Cookie Clicker Classic</a>';
```

This puts the link inside the "topBar" element as a new child, but I want it inside the existing child of the "topBar" element. How do I do this? The child is just within a div tag, it has no id... I have done some reasearch on .appendChild but I haven't found any related help, thus why I am asking here...

I would be very appreciative for any ideas or even a solution to be posted.
Thanks,
Daniel

EDIT: topBar has only one child, it is nameless

also, am I doing something wrong with this?

```
setTimeout(doSomething, 1000);
function doSomething() {
var element =  document.getElementById('particles');
if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
{
var newLink = document.createElement('a');
newLink.setAttribute('href', 'http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/');
newLink.target = 'blank';
document.getElementById('topBar').appendChild(newLink);
var del = document.getElementById('links')
del.parentNode.removeChild(del);
return;
} else {
setTimeout(doSomething, 1000);
}
}
```

EDIT: I have finished! Thanks to everyone for their help, especially Elias Van Ootegem.  This is what I used:

```
var link=document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/');
link.target = 'blank';
link.appendChild(
document.createTextNode('Cookie Clicker Classic')
);
var add = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1]; //this picked the second div tag in the whole document
if(add.lastChild) add.insertBefore(link,add.lastChild); //appending it to the end of the child
else add.prependChild(link);
```

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: You want to append it to existing child. do this existing child have an id, or you want to append to its first child or last child or before or after any chuld, please clarify

Comment: How many children does `topBar` have, and in which one you want to add?

Comment: Please, don't use `innerHTML`: it's [non-standard](http://www.webstandards.org/2006/04/13/dom-builder/), and is possibly [subject to change in the future](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml), read the section titled _"2.5 Dynamic markup insertion"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create the node:

```
var newLink = document.createElement('a');
//set attributes
newLink.setAttribute('href', 'http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/');
newLink.target = 'blank';//preferred way is using setAttribute, though
//add inner text to link:
newLink.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode('Cookie Clicker Classic')//standard way, not innerHTML
);
```

Then, append the child, [using `appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild):

```
document.getElementById('topBar').appendChild(newLink);
```

Or, given your update (your deleting some other element), [use `replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild):

```
document.getElementById('topBar').replaceChild(
    newLink,//new
    document.getElementById('links')//old, will be removed
);
```

And you're there!

Comment: that just does <a href="http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/" target="blank"></a> I need it like this <a href="http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/" target="blank">Cookie Clicker Classic</a> how do i ad the "Cookie Clicker Classic" at the end?

Comment: @ZacktonJochem: fixed that... `newLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode('link text'))`

Comment: Your method puts it after the child but before the end of the parent element so it does <div id=topBar><div>(child stuff)</div> <a href="orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/"; target="blank">Cookie Clicker Classic</a> </div> still need it in the child not after the child has finished. Thank you for your time so far, just about there, sorry

Comment: @ZacktonJochem: Yes, it does, just like `innerHTML +=` does (appends html string to existing html). the name `appendChild` does imply the element is _appended_ to the existing nodes in that particular element... what did you expect?

Comment: so this basically does the same as the innerHTML method, but is better because it doesn't use the innerHTML YAY! this will definatly help others, but I need it within that child element sorry. Is it possible to do something like  document.getElementById('topBar.div(or .child)').appendChild(newLink);?

Comment: @ZacktonJochem: If you need it withing another element, then call the `appendChild` element _on that element_: `document.body.appendChild(elem);` will append to the body, `document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(elem);` will append the element to the `foo` element... I've edited my answer, too, to demonstrate how you can _replace_ children

Comment: ok, so it is inside the child now but i want what is inside the "links" element inside the child, not the whole "links" element.

What is happening:

<div id="topBar">
 <div> (child stuff) 
  <div id="links" style="display:block;position:absolute;right:8px;top:4px;"><a href="http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/" target="blank">Cookie Clicker Classic</a></div>
 </div>
</div>

What I want:

<div id="topBar">
 <div> (child stuff) 
 <a href="http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/" target="blank">Cookie Clicker Classic</a></div>
 </div>
</div>

How do i add grey boxes to show code..

Comment: If you want what is inside an element, then do something like `document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('*')` <-- returns a NodeList (array like object). Or, a one-liner `document.querySelectorAll('#links > *')`

Comment: @ZacktonJochem: But this really is stuff for follow-up questions, because I'm getting the feeling I'm giving 1-on-1 lessons here. This question was about appending a new element to an existing one. Did my answer solve it? Then please accept it, did it not, then please tell me what errors you've gotten... if you want to know how to put a new element and how to process a node-list, then post a question... because that's not what comments are for

Comment: @ZacktonJochem: I'd rather not, well, not unless you pay me. _We_ are not close to completion... _you_ are, if you were to hire me, then there is a _we_ in this story, but ATM, there is not

Comment: All i need is to get the return from document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('(star)') into a variable and then use that variable to add it to the child. Something like "var return = document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('*')" then go "document.getElementById('topBar').appendChild(return);" or whatever it would be...

Comment: as you can probably tell, i'm not a total pro at Javascript and you have been a lot of help, and I thank you for that, do you wish for me to make the previous comment into a new question and carry on from there? even if you don't carry on helping

Comment: very well, I'll bite: `var children = document.querySelectorAll('#list > *');` (or getElementByID().getElementsByTagName()), then: `for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++){ document.getElementById('topBar').appendChild(children[i].cloneNode(true));}`. I'm cloning the elements, because you're deleting the `list` element in your snippet somewhere. Basically, it's a simple loop over an array-like object, appending each child to its new parent

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, it was midnight where I am, last time I posed... after applying your updated method, it still is not how I need the allocation, but it is definitely close to perfect. This URL http://imgur.com/nhD5nOc shows what the allocation is after your updated method and http://imgur.com/PuXPWpH shows what i need the allocation to be. Basically I just need that, now perfectly formatted line to be inside that first and only child... If I am doing something wrong, please tell me, if this is meant to work. Thanks, Daniel

Comment: @ZacktonJochem: instead of appending the `<a>` node to the `document.getElementById('topBar')` element, you need to append it to the inner div, which can be gotten like so: `document.getElementById('topBar').getElementsByTagName('div')[0]`. Appending the link, therefore is done like so: `document.getElementById('topBar').getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(newLink);`. That's what you're after

Comment: I DID IT! I worked out my own method anyway, but I thank you so, so much for helping me, I wouldn't have come to a solution without your ideas! look at the updated question to see how I worked it out. thanks again, Daniel